# The empty path didn't match any of these - Django 2 By Example

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to complete the Django Girls blog in the Django 2 by example book. I ran into this error:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6QFr.png)

This is the code in my urls.py:
[code in mysite/urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz73z.png)

Here is the code in the blog/urls.py

[code in blog/urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVHpp.png)

I did add this 'blog.apps.BlogConfig' to settings.py
I followed carefully the instructions but somehow couldn't fix the problem. Can you please help me?

Thanks a ton

Comment: Try copy pasting the code directly, avoid images for code to make it easy for us to help ;)

Comment: Feedback noted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

add this snippet in `/mysite2/urls.py`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def empty_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Empty View")


urlpatterns = [
    ... your code
    path('', empty_view, name='empty_view'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an empty path in `mysite/urls.py` -- like the first entry in `blog/urls.py`-- that goes somewhere. Either to the same view from just `/blog` or to another view of your choice.

That's the file that get searched through, and you currently only define paths that start with `/admin` and `/blog`, so it doesn't know what to do for the empty case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to add some entries in the blog/urls.py to mysite/urls.py but none worked. I am a newbie in this. Can you be more specific on what I should add?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that as I was following detailed instructions from Django 2 By Example, the issue I had was standard due to the way the authors wanted to teach newbies like me to develop an app. I asked my professor and he confirmed that. It's weird in a sense that the book never mentioned this issue. Thanks for all the help.